# JPA transaction spanned over several postbacks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, transactions

I need to create a simple JEE application which could have two modes. First, it automatically stores each modification to the database, and second, all the changes are stored on demand. Is it possible to start one JPA transaction and span it over many postbacks on a given stateful bean and commit changes (or rollback) when a user clicks some button?

I tried to set the following parameters on my bean:
@Stateful
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)

and also for EntityManager:
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)

but I get the following exception when I try to commit:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is not active in the current thread.

If it is not possible like that, what is the easiest way to create the above functionality?

Comment: How is implemented the stateful bean client?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you forgot to open a transaction. You made everything correct, but additional you have to inject in your @Stateful bean a `UserTransaction` (given your PersistenceContext is JTA and not RESOURCE_LOCAL) and then to start a transaction before comitting the changes.

Comment: Yes, I do start a transaction:
    `@Resource  
    private UserTransaction tx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            tx.begin();
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "CALL Bean.initialize, transaction started successfuly");
        } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Begin transaction unsuccessful: {0}", e.toString());
        }
    }`